# Mysql + copying data of one column(table1) to column of (table2)

Tags: .net, mysql, sql, asp-classic

I have two tables. One is EmployeeDatabase and other is EmployeeSalary.

Both has a column column employeeid...i want to fetch all the employeeid from EmployeeDatabase and fill it to the EmployeeSalary Table keeping in mind that no record get duplicated in salary table...i have made the employeeid column as unique in both table.

How to write query for this.

Comment: Is **table1** and **table2** of same type. @arrest warrant

Comment: Can you please post the structure of the tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement
- join both tables using `LEFT JOIN` so you can filter which ID is not present on the other table using `IS NULL` function

Query,

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary (EmployeeID)
SELECT   a.EmployeeID
FROM     EmployeeDatabase a
         LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary b
              ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
WHERE    b.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e81c/1)